# Query about setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

Since past couple of months, I have been doing a lot of JS, but I have never really learned it in a college/from a book etc.

Here is a question:

```
$scope.selectTab = function($index, tab) {
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[$index];
    $scope.data.tabSelected = tab;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.clear();
        console.log($scope.template);
        console.log(document.getElementById("SomeDiv"))
        console.log("Going to draw now...")
        draw_analytics($scope); // Draw on SomeDiv
    }, 0);
}
```

while the above code works; but the below one doesn't.

```
$scope.selectTab = function($index, tab) {
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[$index];
    $scope.data.tabSelected = tab;
    console.clear();
    console.log($scope.template);
    console.log(document.getElementById("SomeDiv"))
    console.log("Going to draw now...")
    draw_analytics($scope);
}
```

I am using AngularJS for some tabbing thing, but that is irrelevant I guess.
In the top code, when I try to get `SomeDiv` dom, I actually get it's HTML content, while in the bottom code, `null` is returned.

Comment: What do you mean `fsb`? Nothing in that code has that.

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? if there are any errors, please post those here

Comment: Sorry, I meant that same `SomeDiv`. Well if the bottom code, `SomeDiv` is `null` (though it shouldn't be since `$scope.template = $scope.templates[$index];` assigns the right HTML to it). While in the top code, it will be just fine.

Comment: The only difference between the two is that in the first, the code in the *setTimeout* will be called after the *selectTab* function has finished, whereas in the second it wont. So if *SomeDiv* is there in the first and not in the second, there is something happening to make it available.

Comment: Check you're executing after the DOM has fully loaded.. that's the only difference that comes to mind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use settimeout with an anonymous function, it doesn't execute it right away. It adds it to a queue to be executed after the current events finish.

This is opposed to running it without settimeout, which just executes it immediately.

If I had to guess, "SomeDiv" is being created or manipulated with the tab change.  So running the code right away may cause a situation where the code executes before the div is actually created.  While calling "settimeout" will wait until the current events complete before executing.  Although it looks like it's inline with the event, it's really just scheduling the anonymous function to run at the end.

I created a fiddle to illustrate what I'm talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/pS54r/

The first button using settimeout, the second button doesn't.

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {
    WriteToDiv('First Button 1');
    setTimeout(function () {
        WriteToDiv('First Button 2');
    }, 0);
    WriteToDiv('First Button 3');
});

$('#clickme2').click(function () {
    WriteToDiv('Second Button 1');
    WriteToDiv('Second Button 2');
    WriteToDiv('Second Button 3');
});
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot, I get it now. Is there any better way to add a function to be executed after the parent function is done? Like I still want to call that "draw_analytics($scope);" just after the "SomeDiv" is created.

Comment: To my knowledge, the first way you had it is the best way to have it work and make it easily maintainable.  I'm no expert though, so there might be something I'm not aware of.